# Python: intersection of nested lists where order matters

Tags: python, list, intersection, nested-lists

I would like to find the intersection between nested lists while maintaining the order.

```
taxa = [['E_pyrifoliae_Ep1_96', 'Bacteria', 'Proteobacteria', 'Gammaproteobacteria', 'Enterobacteriales', 'Enterobacteriaceae', 'Erwinia'],
 ['E_amylovora_CFBP1430', 'Bacteria', 'Proteobacteria', 'Gammaproteobacteria', 'Enterobacteriales', 'Enterobacteriaceae', 'Erwinia'], 
 ['E_amylovora_ATCC49946', 'Bacteria', 'Proteobacteria', 'Gammaproteobacteria', 'Enterobacteriales', 'Enterobacteriaceae', 'Erwinia']]
```

To find the intersection I have:

```
set.intersection(*map(set, taxa))
```

or

```
set(taxa[0]).intersection(*taxa)
```

but the original order is not kept.

```
set(['Erwinia', 'Gammaproteobacteria', 'Enterobacteriaceae', 'Enterobacteriales', 'Proteobacteria', 'Bacteria'])
```

Basically, what I need to do is find the last common element between the nested lists (they are taxanomic classifications ). So I don't need to find all the intersections, just the last one or all of them when I can just call on the last entry.

```
intersection_lst[-1]
```

In this instance I want the output to be 'Erwinia'.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what version of python are you working with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find the intersection, then reimpose order.

```
intersection_set = set.intersection(*map(set, taxa))
intersection_lst = [t for t in taxa[0] if t in intersection_set]
```

Or, if you are inordinately fond on one-liners:

```
sorted(set.intersection(*map(set, taxa)), key=lambda x: taxa[0].index(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this with:

```
[t for t in taxa[0] if all(t in l for l in taxa)]
# ['Bacteria', 'Proteobacteria', 'Gammaproteobacteria', 'Enterobacteriales', 'Enterobacteriaceae', 'Erwinia']
```

If the lists are large, it would be more efficient to do:

```
taxa_set = map(set, taxa)    
[t for t in taxa[0] if all(t in l for l in taxa_set)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain

d=OrderedDict()
for elem in chain(*taxa):
    if elem in d:
        d[elem] += 1
    else:
        d[elem] = 1

intersection_lst = [ k for k,v in d.items() if v == len(taxa) ]
```

Note that this only works if the inner lists are unique.

And here's an example using an ordered counter:

```
from collections import OrderedDict,Counter
from itertools import chain

class OrderedCounter(Counter,OrderedDict): pass

d = OrderedCounter(chain(*taxa))
intersection_lst = [ k for k,v in d.items() if v == len(taxa) ]
```

*still only works if elements are unique in each sublist*

Comment: This won't work if an element appears multiple times in an inner list.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today. In my benchmarks, using `set.intersection` was the fastest way of achieving this in CPython, taking ~170us with my dataset.

In PyPy however, a hand-rolled function taking advantage of the ordering took only ~80us, *nearly double the speed of CPython*! The same function in CPython took ~6200us.

Here is that function for posterity:

```
def intersect_ordered(a, b):
    matches = []
    ia, ib = 0, 0
    la, lb = len(a), len(b)
    while ia < la and ib < lb:
        va, vb = a[ia], b[ib]
        if va < vb:
            ia += 1
        elif vb < va:
            ib += 1
        else:
            matches.append(va)
            ia += 1
            ib += 1
    return matches
```